# Run node server, make curl request and then kill server in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, curl, next.js, command-line

I have the following simple Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16

COPY . .
RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

It runs a NextJS application. I need to make two CURL Requests from the container but, I can't do:

```
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev", "&&", "curl", "localhost:3000/.....
```

Because the following error appears:

```
error - Invalid project directory provided, no such directory: /&&
```

It seems that it's trying to catch the curl command as a directory or a flag.

What can I do? Also, I need to kill the server when the two CURL Requests are done (kill the docker container).

Comment: Use a custom shell script as entry point?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the 'exec' form of the CMD statement which doesn't run a shell. That's usually preferred because it takes up a bit less memory.

But `&&` is a shell operator, so you need a shell to be able to do that. So instead you can use the 'shell' form of the CMD statement and do

```
CMD npm run dev && curl localhost:3000/.....
```

More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).

Comment: That curl command won't run because "npm run dev" won't release the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following line:

```
CMD (npm run dev &) && sleep 10 && curl -X PUT localhost:3000/api/1 && curl -X PUT localhost:3000/api/2
```

It is not the best solution because I can't control the time when "npm run dev" is running. But in my case, it takes 3 seconds so it is safer for me, so it works.

Anyways, a better solution for the "sleep 10" could be to check the server until this is ready, in a for loop.